# Inventory tracking - vlookup with subtraction from running total

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup, sumifs

I hope I can explain this clearly enough to get a little help. I've tried looking for an answer by haven't found anything that quite works.

The Problem:

We receive orders from our customers that have the same SKU on multiple PO's (purchase orders). We need to move the inventory from its current location to the DOCK from 4 other locations. The inventory does not go directly to the DOCK. It usually has to pass through 2 or more locations to get processed. so for example SKU0001 starts in LOC2, moves to LOC3 and then gets moved to the DOCK.

What I need:

I have 3 different orders (PO's) that need SKU0001:
PO9999 need 25 units of SKU0001
PO8888 need 10 units of SKU0001
PO7777 need 50 units of SKU0001

I have a grand total of 100 units of SKU0001 in stock, plenty to fulfill the order. The location of the inventory is as follows:
30 units of SKU0001 in LOC1
10 units of SKU0001 in LOC2
20 units of SKU0001 in LOC3
15 units of SKU0001 in LOC4
25 units of SKU0001 in DOCK

I need to be able to determine how many units of SKU0001 have been moved to the DOCK, how many units are in either `LOC1, LOC2, LOC3 and LOC4` and how many units are missing to fulfill the order. As I mentioned SKU0001 will appear on the orders tab multiple times as it will be on multiple PO's, so I also need to be able to subtract the number that have been moved to the DOCK from the running total so the next instance of SKU0001 on the list has an accurate location count for the 5 locations listed above.

Right now we are having to manually enter the numbers based on the locations of the inventory, with a few SKU it's not a problem, bu we usually have about 500 SKU and with multiple updates required through the day, it can be very time consuming to update the data.

As I cannot attach any file or add links I will have to give you a break down of the file I am working with,

First Tab: Orders (9 Columns) This is where the formula needs to be added to columns LOC1 thru DOCK.

```
PO | SKU | QTY_REQ | LOC1 | LOC2 | LOC3| LOC4 | DOCK | MISSING |
```

Second Tab: Inventory Qty and Locations (7 Columns)

```
SKU | LOC1 | LOC2 | LOC3 | LOC4| DOCK| TOTAL_INVENTORY |
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have stated the problem, and your goals, but what have you tried.

Comment: (Wow, that's really long & hard to follow.)  We don't want files but we do want sample data.  :)  A good way to add data (like the headers) when you [edit] your question  is to put it in a `code block` which you can do by highlighting the text and clicking the `{ }` button on the editing toolbar (above the question) or hitting CTRL+K. In-line code blocks can also be acheivied in comments or in the questions by surrounding the word or phrase with `\`` `backticks`.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to build a customized inventory system for the accounting or purchasing department. That might be a tad more complex than a *'specific programming problem'*. [Hire a programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?med=site-ui&ref=jobs-tab).

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out how many items have been allocated, so if the item appears again on another order, we can calculate from the new total and not the grand total we had had the start.  
reen Balls)

Comment: I think I made it sound a lot more complicated than it is.  Maybe this will help simplify it: 

PEOPLE (SKU)
Mike
Sally
Tom

Colored Balls (Inventory with QTY)
Red Ball 150
Blue Ball 100
Green Ball 200

Comment: So, Order ID1 has the following People(SKU) and Colored Balls (QTY)
Mike 25 Red Balls (this would leave 125 Red Balls)
Sally 20 Blue Balls (this would leave 80 Blue Balls)
Tom 30 Green Balls (this would leave 170 Green Balls)

The next Order ID is ID2 and has the following People(SKU) and Colored Balls (QTY)
Mike 30 Red Balls (this would leave 95 Red Balls)
Sally 45 Blue Balls (this would leave 35 Blue Balls)
Tom 50 Green Balls (this would leave 120 Green Balls)